# NO javadoc style comment in CDT?

Tags: c, javadoc, comments, eclipse-cdt

I use CDT to do a C project. but when I type /* and a newline
 I got something like

```
/**
*
*/
```

but not

```
    /**
   * @param
   * @return
   */
```

I tried to edit the code template, but there's no $tag variable.

I'm using CDT 7.02. + ubuntu 10.04 LTs

what should I do . Thank you!!!

Comment: project-> properties -> C/C++ general  Enable project specific settings choose Doxygen

Answer (score 6):

CDT supports doxygen out of the box. However there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of the ${tags} variable found in JDT.

To enable doxygen globally go to Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor. Find the Documentation Tool Comments section and set Workspace Default to Doxygen.

To enable doxygen for a specific project right click on the project and select Properties. Then on the C/C++ General page click "enable project specific settings" then select doxygen.